# How to use “discipline“?

Tags: word-usage

I want to know the usage of this word as much as possible.
I only know that “discipline” is equivalent to rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word ***discipline*** comes from the Latin meaning student, learner, or follower.

In English there are essentially three uses of the word: one as a verb, and two others as a noun.

The *noun* form denotes either an area of study or specialized learning,

- Ralph specialized in the discipline of cognitive therapy, commonly
  called "talk therapy."
- The university offers a variety of disciplines in both the soft- and hard sciences, such as the communication arts and mircro-biology, respectively.

or the virtue of being able to submit to the rigors of learning, as well as the ability to be self-controlled when experiencing stress:

- Julie did not have the discipline to stick to the printed schedule.
- Fred was fired from his job for showing a lack of discipline in key areas of his work and job description.

As a *verb*, to discipline a person is to impose correction and/or punishment in the hope that a negative pattern of behavior will be changed into something more positive or more approved of by the person administering the discipline.

- Ricky's dad warned him that if his behavior did not improve, his dad would have to administer some severe discipline.
- If you don’t correct your children, you don’t love them. If you love them, you will be quick to discipline them (Proverbs 13:24 ERV).
- Listen to advice and accept discipline; then you, too, will become wise.(Proverbs 19:20 ERV)

Both the noun- and verb forms of the word discipline and its cognates can often be used in tandem, as in the following sentence:

- Discipline yourself, or someone else may be forced to discipline you.
- Any academic discipline requires a leaner to discipline himself or herself if they want to succeed.